Can a matrix have 2 free variables? (Like $x_1$ and $x_3$)
I stuck at a point while solving eigen vectors, here is my reduced form after applying the eigen value in $(A - \lambda I)$.
3×3 matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
It's a 3×3 matrix,
Here the last row doesn't have a pivot so $x_3$ is a free variable right and also there is no way to calculate $x_1$ so I need to take arbitrarily a value for that or I'm wrong? (I put the zero row at last because that's what they said to do in ref.)

The first pivot is $x_2$, and $x_3$ the second one.  Then you run out of numbers.  $x_1$ is free.

Please provide the original matrix.
